# for a given guid and a given machine: can i determine if the guid was made on the machine?

Tags: guid

Given that some Guid generating algorithms use some consistent information from the computer:
Could you at least rule out a machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the algorithm that was used to make the GUID.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID#Algorithm

"In the OSF-specified algorithm for generating new (V1) GUIDs, the user's network card MAC address is used as a base for the last group of GUID digits, which means, for example, that a document can be tracked back to the computer that created it. This privacy hole was used when locating the creator of the Melissa virus.[3] Most of the other digits are based on the time while generating the GUID.

V1 GUIDs which contain a MAC address and time can be identified by the digit "1" in the first position of the third group of digits, for example {2F1E4FC0-81FD-**1**1DA-9156-00036A0F876A}."

So if you have a match between the GUID and a computer's mac address, it's very likely that the GUID was made there. If there isn't, it could still have been made there, since no one forces you to use a particular GUID algorithm.